# Android file path error

Tags: android, android-volley

I choose an image from galley and I get the path as:

`file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160718_165644_HDR.jpg`

and the image gets loaded as bitmap. However when I pass the image path in volleyplus [multipart request](https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus/blob/master/library/src/com/android/volley/request/MultiPartRequest.java) for uploading, I get file not found exception. However, when I give the path as:

```
sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160718_165644_HDR.jpg
```

then everything works fine. How do I get the image path in this format.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: You should give the path as `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160718_165644_HDR.jpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substring` method to delete `file://` part of your path or

use this method to get real path :

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "YourFileName"
```

Comment: Only the protocol header `file://` has to be deleted as the path starts with "/storage/.......".

Comment: There was no need to edit that. And now my remark does not make sense.